# The mongodb QueryBuilder method near ()' parameter's unit?

Tags: mongodb, 2d, query-builder

I am now using MongoDB java driver to do 2D query.I am calling QueryBuilder's method [near(double,double double)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html#near%28double,%20double,%20double%29) to do my query.But the api document doesn't ever tolder me the unit of the third param,its unit is meter?kilometer or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You can review

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near

and especially http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/#op._S_maxDistance

then I'll quote that page

> The measuring units for the maximum distance are determined by the
>   coordinate system in use. For GeoJSON point object, specify the
>   distance in meters, not radians.